# pd.excelwriter not appending to bottom of sheet1. Instead creating new sheets? python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

my code isn't working to append new data to the bottom of an existing excel file. It keeps creating new sheets in the file but I need it to append to sheet1 with the new data frame. The headers are all the same.

> pip freeze = pandas python: 3.8.10 |openpyxl: 3.0.9 | pandas: 1.1.2
> |xlrd 2.0.1

```
df1= [Order Amount:   Item Name:      Date:]
     [7000          Plastic Cup       7/1/2022]


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('order_history.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = load_workbook('order_history.xlsx')
writer.sheets= dict((ws.title,ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
reader = pd.read_excel('order_history.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
order_df1.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow= len(reader)+1)
writer.close()
```

This has been a problem I haven't figured out for hours please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas 1.4 set the following parameter (see the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)):

```
if_sheet_exists='overlay'
```

Otherwise try with:

```
startrow = writer.sheets['sheet1'].max_row
```